# Rails and Flash params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, rest, parameters

I'm trying to post a value to my rails website from Flash.

What I've got is a URL of `http://localhost:3000/users/new` which I post to from Flash. The variable I'm sending as a POST method is `score=xx`. For some reason I can't pick up the value in my rails controller in the new method: `@newScore = params[:score]`. If I change the method to a GET I can get to the value with no problem. So should I be using the params hash on a POST method?

If someone can advice I'd much appreciate it.

Comment: Is the `:score` param being received in the controller? Check in the controller by putting `debug params` in the view for the `users/new` action.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using custom routes? Or do you just do `resources :users`? Better run `rake routes`. `/users/new` is usually a GET, which makes sense, since you're fetching an object. The `create` action is the only POST, and that maps to `/users`. Doing `/users/new` as a POST breaks REST.

POST data is not allowed on a GET method. Any parameters will be put on the query string in the URL. Those parameters will still show up in the `params` hash.

**Edit**

If you're actually trying to create a user with this REST call, you need to POST to http://localhost:3000/users, **not** http://localhost:3000/users/new

**Edit**

Unfortunately I don't know enough about how flash sends POST requests to tell you why your params aren't coming accross. However, if you're trying to get to the form, you definitely need a GET to http://localhost:3000/users/new. You say that you can pick up the variable just fine when you do a GET, right? So you don't need to do a POST.

If you don't want the user to be able to edit the score, then you save the value to a variable in the controller, and when you render the view, you put that value in an non-editable element, like a disabled text box or maybe even just a label.

**Edit**

If you can figure out how to get your Post data across from Flash to Rails, you'll need to do a POST to `users_url`, and then you can modify your `create` method to send back the id of the user that was created. Then when you get that back, you can make another call to edit the user with that id, leaving the score field disabled. Best of luck.

Comment: yes /user/new is a GET. Could you recommend a way around this? Should I create custom routes for each url, instead of using resources :users

Comment: What I'm saying is, /users/new *should* be a GET, otherwise it breaks REST. So why would you try to do a POST to a GET method? It doesn't make sense. Why do you want to do a POST?

Comment: @Peter: are you trying to *create* a new user? If so you need to post to http://localhost:3000/users and send your post data.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to create a new user with a score value that the user got from the flash. I need to get to the new form so the user can fill in there details, along with there score. I want to do a POST so they can't change there score manually when on the form.

Comment: doing a POST to http://localhost:3000/users still doesn't work, as it's not picking up the variable. This is what I get when I do a debug params: --- !map:HashWithIndifferentAccess action: create controller: users

Comment: If you need to get to the form, then you need to do a GET to users/new. Pick up the param in the controller and set a variable, and when the view gets rendered, plug the value of that variable into an uneditable field. Maybe just a label or a disabled text field.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help. If I put the score in the URL then the user can just change the value within the url and give them selfs a high score. I'll have to see what else I can do.

Comment: Maybe inspect the request? See if your stuff is there somewhere? You should also post your Flash code so maybe someone who knows more about Flash can see if you're sending your Post data incorrectly. Sorry I couldn't be of more help. But if you're going to do a POST, you'll have to POST to localhost:3000/users, and then maybe your controller can send back the id of the object that was created so that you can make another call to edit that user, leaving the 'score' field disabled.